# Adobe Javascript _ is not a function error

Tags: javascript, adobe

I'm trying to extract pages from a big PDF based on key words. I'm getting hung up in that many methods I use come back and say they're "not a function" but they show up in the Adobe documentation. I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong within the loop.

```
// Define the trigger phrase
var triggerPhrase = "help";

// Define the output directory path
var outputDirPath = "/C/Users/x/"; //This is right, I've just changed it for this

// Get the total number of pages in the document
var numPages = this.numPages;

// Loop through the pages, looking for the trigger phrase
for (var i = 0; i < numPages; i++) {
  // Get the text content of the current page
  var words = this.getPageNthWord(i, 0);
  var pageText = words.join(" ");

  // Check if the trigger phrase is in the page text
  if (pageText.includes(triggerPhrase)) {
    // This page contains the trigger phrase
    var startPage = i;
    var endPage = startPage;
    i++;

    // Keep looping until the next page with the trigger phrase is found or we reach the end of the document
    while (i < numPages && !this.getPageNthWord(i, 0).join(" ").includes(triggerPhrase)) {
      endPage = i;
      i++;
    }

    // Extract the pages between the start and end pages to a new PDF file
    var outputFilePath = outputDirPath + "pages_" + (startPage + 1) + "-" + (endPage + 1) + ".pdf";
    this.extractPages({
      nStart: startPage,
      nEnd: endPage,
      cPath: outputFilePath
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post the exact error message and indicate which line it's happening on.

Comment: Where do you define `this`? That's usually used in object or class methods, not top-level code, it refers to the object that the method was called on.